# Find unused public web service([WebMethod]) methods with Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, code-analysis

I found a way to check the unused public/private methods with resharper but can we also check the methods with annotation [WebMethod]. So that i can make sure that it is also not accessible from my JavaScript code as well.

Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short: No, you cannot**

*Details:* `[WebMethod]` is a way to define the methods that you want to expose for **http request** calls, it has to support all types of client (imagine a scenario that you have multiple web/mobile applications that calling the same web service). **Technically you will never know how many applications are consuming the web service**. `Resharper` is just a productivity tool, it cannot be that smart :).

Cheers.